# Google notified me that I have a sudden spike in 404's, but they are pages that don't exist

Tags: 404, spam, crawl-errors

I'm pretty puzzled by this, so any direction would be helpful.

The only thing hosted on this server is basically two word press instances with my personal site and another. Everything's been great, but then I got an email letting me know that there are a bunch of new 404's.

The URLs look like spam pages, and I'm 100% sure that they don't exist in my WordPress instance.

It appears to me that some spam site has just decided to link to a bunch of nonexistent pages on my site. Is this a reasonable assumption? Should I bother to look at this any further?

The list looks like this:

```
blog-forex/1182-Gielisch+Gcm+Forex-cb.html
404
11/2/16

2
blog-forex/6691-Exchange+Rates+Of+The+Market+Forex+Nigeria+Today-52.html
404
11/2/16

3
blog-forex/4918-%D8%A8%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%B5%D8%A9+%D9%88%D8%B8%D8%A7%D8%A6%D9%81+%D9%81%D9%8A+%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%85%D9%86-2b.html
404
11/2/16

4
blog-forex/13789-One+Hour+Binary+Options+Strategy+Explanation-f.html
404
11/2/16

5
blog-forex/14381-Breve+Historia+De+La+Bolsa+De+Valores+De+Caracas,+Venezuela-d2.html
404
11/1/16

6
blog-forex/1611-Trade+In+The+Market+Forex+Lessons-fc.html
404
11/2/16

7
blog-forex/13522-Vegas+Wave+Strategy+Based+On+Elliott+Indicator+Forex-4f.html
404
11/2/16

8
blog-forex/5882-Forex+Currency+Converter+Togo-53.html
404
11/2/16

9
blog-forex/10196-Forex+Beer+Ads+1950'S-c0.html
404
11/1/16

10
blog-forex/1505-Meilleures+Forex+Sites+De+N%C3%A9gociation+En+C%C3%B4te+D'Ivoire-89.html
404
11/1/16

11
blog-forex/12785-L%C3%A1ska+Zar%C3%A1baj%C3%BA+V+Forex+Obchodovanie+Na+Slovenskom-78.html
404
11/2/16

12
blog-forex/10776-Kotaksecurities+Online+Trading+Account-16.html
404
11/2/16

13
blog-forex/4805-Ko%C4%BEko+Burzov%C3%A9+Trhy,+Na+Slovenskom-8a.html
404
11/1/16

14
blog-forex/13566-Statistiky+Kde,+Jak+Vyd%C4%9Blat+Pen%C3%ADze+Online+V+%C4%8Cesk%C3%A9+Republice-aa.html
404
11/1/16

15
blog-forex/14432-Mercados+Stock+Exchange,+Em+Portugal-7b.html
404
11/1/16

16
blog-forex/5036-%E0%A6%AC%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%82%E0%A6%B2%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A6%E0%A7%87%E0%A6%B6%E0%A7%87+%E0%A6%85%E0%A6%A8%E0%A6%B2%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%87%E0%A6%A8%E0%A7%87+%E0%A6%85%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%A5+%E0%A6%B9%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%AE+%E0%A6%AB%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%BF-b.
404
11/2/16
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the search console - it will show which pages are linking to these 404 pages.

If these links are all external than there is probably nothing to worry about - just hacked sites linking to your domain. It could be that somebody tried to hack your site as well but did not succeed

If part of the links are coming from pages on your site, you site was probably hacked.

To be on the save side - change all passwords (cms/server) and check if you are using the most recent version of all the plugins you are using - if not update them.

You might want to check these resources as well
[My site has been hacked](https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked) and
[Google help for hacked sites](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/hacked/)

Comment: Check the *CMS software for updates, themes, and plugins*. Use https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/search?execution=e2s1 to check versions. Reset all passwords yourself not by users at login. Use an anti-virus against your hard-drive, some viruses effect CMSs, and use an online scanner to ensure your site has not been hacked. Manully check your system for anything out of place. Generally, links such as these are created by compromised systems to another compromised system. It may not mean your site has a problem, however, it is better to be safe than sorry. Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for the tips. It appears that my word press instance was not the thing that was compromised. There was actually an extra directory added in my web root that contained all of these. I deleted the directory, changed all the passwords, and updated all of the software. I'd like to do more, but it's just a bunch of old personal blogs.